# The M3 annotation is undeclared

Tags: rascal

I have an M3 object created by

```
M3 m3 = createM3FromDirectory(project)
```

for some project directory. Furthermore, I have

```
alias M3Dependencies = map[str depType, rel [loc from, loc to] dependencies];
M3Dependencies result = ();
```

In the preamble of my module I have:

```
extend lang::java::m3::Core;
extend lang::java::jdt::Project;
import lang::java::jdt::m3::AST;
import analysis::m3::Registry;
```

When I do

```
result["extends"]     = m3@extends;
```

I get an exception, saying *Undeclared annotation: extends on M3*

The code from which this sample was taken worked fine in 2015 and 2016, now it is broken because of this exception.
Could you please tell me what goes wrong?

Cheers, Steven Klusener

Comment: PS. When I want to reconstruct the error and construct a different M3 object I get the error *Can not call a constructed M3 node as a function*. What is going on here?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry about this. We are slowly phasing out annotations and they are being replaced by keyword parameters. The name of each keyword parameter is identical to the name of the annotation it replaces. See, for instance, `lang::java::m3::Core` where you can find this definition:

```
data M3(
    rel[loc from, loc to] extends = {},            // classes extending classes and interfaces extending interfaces
    rel[loc from, loc to] implements = {},         // classes implementing interfaces
    rel[loc from, loc to] methodInvocation = {},   // methods calling each other (including constructors)
    rel[loc from, loc to] fieldAccess = {},        // code using data (like fields)
    rel[loc from, loc to] typeDependency = {},     // using a type literal in some code (types of variables, annotations)
    rel[loc from, loc to] methodOverrides = {},    // which method override which other methods
    rel[loc declaration, loc annotation] annotations = {}
);
```

So where you previously had to write `m3@extends` you should now write `m3.extends`. Hope this helps.